# Crawl only internal links from a website using python

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a crawler that only processes the internal links of a site. I am using python 2.7, beautiful soup and requests and I need all the internal links (absolutes and relatives).

Client of mine requested me a crawler for a site, but I want it to crawl only internal links. I need it to ignore jpg/png/gif and other kind of urls, so it processes only pages.

```
import re, request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def processUrl(url):
    if not url in checkedUrls:
        try:
            if 'text/html' in requests.head(url).headers['Content-Type']:
                req=requests.get(url)
                if req.status_code==200:
                    print url
                    checkedUrls.append(url)
                    html=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
                    pages=html.find_all('a')
                    for page in pages:
                        url=page.get('href')
                        processUrl(url)
        except:
            pass

checekdUrls=[]
url='http://sampleurl.com'
processUrl(url)
```

Comment: there really isn't a question in there, as it's more of a "can you check my code?" kind of thing. There are other places you can post to do that. If you provide an actually url or code that gives an output, and show that it's giving you undesired outputs, then provide that. Have you tested it with the url? Is it not working? How is it not working? Also, I'm not familiar with it, but I see people talk about [scrappy](https://scrapy.org/) quite often when trying to do this. more examples [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/web-scraping-in-python-using-scrapy/)

Comment: You just need to put in an additional logic before you start crawling to check that the domain is the same. If it's not just return back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, with the addition of the logic i commented above.

```
import re, request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def processUrl(url, domain, checkedUrls=[]):
    if domain not in url:
        return checkedUrls

    if not url in checkedUrls:
        try:
            if 'text/html' in requests.head(url).headers['Content-Type']:
                req=requests.get(url)
                if req.status_code==200:
                    print url
                    checkedUrls.append(url)
                    html=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
                    pages=html.find_all('a')
                    for page in pages:
                        url=page.get('href')
                        processUrl(url)
        except:
            pass

    return checkedUrls


checekdUrls=[]
domain = 'sampleurl.com'
url='http://sampleurl.com'
checkedUrls = processUrl(url, domain, checkedUrls)
```

Comment: I tried that already. Failed when found a social network link with a reference to domain.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Selenium config specifications that allow you to crawl within just the same domain automatically. Sounds like you need more specialized handling for your social network case. If checking domains doesn't work then maybe you can try checking the ip address

Comment: On a separate note, your social network link failed probably because your domain is included as a hyperlink variable i.e. ```https://socialnetworksite.com/link?site=sampleurl.com```. If that is the case, then you may just specify your string search to be the full ```http://sampleurl.com```. Special chars in URL are usually escaped so those won't be caught by your string search

Comment: NameError: global name 'checkedUrls' is not defined

Comment: @Mostafa Thanks for pointing out. The variables were not given a global scope. I have updated the function signature

Comment: @kerwei I see other error's... always `except` occur and you pass it.

Comment: @Mostafa That's beyond the scope of OP's question. He wanted a suggestion on how to avoid crawling links that lead to external domain so that is the focus of the answer. It is entirely up to the OP on how he wants to handle other crawling exceptions i.e. element not found. That part of the logic is merely replicated off OP's example.